# Problem with accessing into OCI instance using VScode remote SSH

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code, ssh

I tried to access my VM created on OCI using VScode remote SSH.

I followed the tutorial online and I just cannot get accessed to that.

I got error message everytimelike this:

```
[22:05:41.160] Log Level: 2
[22:05:41.162] remote-ssh@0.78.0
[22:05:41.162] win32 x64
[22:05:41.169] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+elesis", attempt 1
[22:05:41.170] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[22:05:41.170] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[22:05:41.170] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[22:05:41.170] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[22:05:41.170] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[22:05:41.171] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[22:05:41.171] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[22:05:41.171] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[22:05:41.171] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[22:05:41.172] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[22:05:41.172] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[22:05:41.172] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[22:05:41.172] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[22:05:41.173] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[22:05:41.173] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[22:05:41.173] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[22:05:41.222] SSH Resolver called for host: elesis
[22:05:41.223] Setting up SSH remote "elesis"
[22:05:41.261] Using commit id "dfd34e8260c270da74b5c2d86d61aee4b6d56977" and quality "stable" for server
[22:05:41.268] Install and start server if needed
[22:05:42.873] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[22:05:42.956] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[22:05:42.965] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 62778 elesis bash
[22:05:42.970] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:05:43.281] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[22:05:43.282] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[22:05:43.297] > Bad owner or permissions on C:\\Users\\Elesis/.ssh/config
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
>       
[22:05:44.583] "install" terminal command done
[22:05:44.583] Install terminal quit with output:       
[22:05:44.583] Received install output:       
[22:05:44.584] Resolver error: Error: 
    at Function.Create (c:\Users\Elesis\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.78.0\out\extension.js:1:586041)
    at c:\Users\Elesis\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.78.0\out\extension.js:1:583914
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Elesis\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.78.0\out\extension.js:1:584615)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\Elesis\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.78.0\out\extension.js:1:681924)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async c:\Users\Elesis\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.78.0\out\extension.js:1:644564
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Elesis\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.78.0\out\extension.js:1:647909)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\Elesis\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.78.0\out\extension.js:1:645643)
    at async c:\Users\Elesis\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.78.0\out\extension.js:1:722950
[22:05:44.591] ------
```

Here is my SSH config file:

```
  Host elesis
    HostName 168.138.9.67
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile D:\xxx\xxx\xxx\ssh-key-2022-04-23.key
```

I don't know why.
Please help me.

Comment: I would say this question is really specific so nobody could give a proper answer.

Comment: I have fixed it anyway.

Comment: Please post a bit more details on how did you able to solve this problem. It will help other people to find a possible solution to the similar issue.

Comment: I have checked many posts and I think I disabled the inheritance for key file to make this work